# Angular 2 [innerHTML] binding with html file instead of html code

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use `<div [innerHTML]="api_tool_atttibutes | sanitizeHtml"></div>`

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtml implements PipeTransform  {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    transform(v: string) : SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
    }
}

api_tool_atttibutes:string = <input class="form-control" placeholder="Default` Text Field" type="text">
```

`api_tool_atttibutes` is an html code that been set by the component.

I would like to replace the html code (string) with an html page -> that the string will hold the html page path instead of the html code.

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to load the HTML page using the URL (using `http.get(...)`) and then pass it to `api_tools_attributes` or whatever field you bind to `[innerHTML]="..."`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer while using : 'api_tool_atttibutes = this.http.get('./file.html')' i'm getting '[object Object]' in the UI..